# Cannot get cursor out of edit area when editing an answer in Low Quality Posts

Tags: bug, edits

## ***Browser Information***

---

I am using **Chrome** version **32.0.1700.107 m** in **Incognito** mode.

## ***Problem***

---

While trying to edit the last 2 reviews I've had in the **Low Quality Posts** queue, once I start editing and the cursor was inside of the edit area, I could not get it out.

For example, I would try to click the **Edit Summary** textbox, yet the cursor remained inside of the edit area.  I had to eventually just click **Save Edits** or some other button to move on.

[image: screen shot of the problem]

## ***Possible Insight into the Cause of the Issue***

---

If you look at the **[Editing...]** button in the screen shot, it's not disabled.  When you normally edit that button is disabled.

## ***Reproduced Issue***

---

Here is [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4171424) that I ran into.

[image: screen shot of reproduced issue]

As you can see, it also has the **[Editing...]** button enabled. It's disabled until you click inside of the edit area, then it becomes enabled.  After that, you can't do anything with the cursor inside of the edit area.  You can tab out of it, but you then you can't get back into the edit area.  You simply have to cancel out of the entire thing.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian - I've even noticed that sometimes if you use **CTRL+V** as the first change in the edit, that **CTRL+Z** stops working.

Comment: Happened to me a couple of times in IE 10.

Comment: Just had this happen to be in Firefox today...